# Trying to sort by date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a column with dates written as

```
06.06.14
30.06.14
10.06.14
10.06.14
20.07.14
28.05.14
```

When I try and sort it it sorts it based on the first numbers only and ignores the month, year etc.

I read some other answers and they suggested changing the format of the column to date format. So I highlighted the column, clicked format cells and selected date but nothing changes and the column still sorts in the same wrong way.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(2000+RIGHT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))
```

and copy down.

Then sort both cols **A** & **B** by **B**

Comment: You are quite welcome!............the advantage to this technique is that it works with most Regional Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `.` with `/` before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

1- Select the colum, right-clic : Format

2- In format, you have to select "Personalize" then enter "dd.mm.yy",validate

3- Then do a REPLACE ALL for the "." in the select column with "/"

This way you keep the format you choose but Excel understands it as a date, you do not create an extra column and of course you can sort it :-)